# What kind of bridge would reverse DC motor with negative signal

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, bridge

[image]I am not an electrical engineer (aerospace trying to be electrical) and am building a solar tracker. TLDR Goal is to turn on M3 and M4 if signal is positive, and M1 and M2 if signal negative to drive motor rotation direction.  Using a technique similar to the Parker Solar Probe, I am using 2 solar cells to generate a signal to drive a motor left and right, and 2 for a motor up and down. The solar cells oppose each other electrically (+ on one to - on the other, and - to +), and are on opposite sides of the array, so if the sun is to the right, I get a small positive voltage, and if the sun is to the left, I get a negative voltage. Now, these cells are too small to drive the DC motor, so I need either relays or a bridge circuit to increase the power for the solar cells to activate the motor. I don't want to use a microcontroller and prefer analog if possible.

I understand how a bridge circuit can be used to reverse a DC motor, but I understand a bridge assumes the required gate voltages are all positive. Is there a way to drive a motor one way with a small positive signal voltage, and the opposite way with a negative gate voltage? The MOSFET switching on with a negative gate and off at zero is what I need but don't see how.

Edit: on further research it looks like a bidirectional P-channel MOSFET would switch a negative voltage with a negative gate voltage.

Comment: "A technique similar to the parker solar probe"... or similar to the more common and well-known CD-ROM drive.

Comment: It sounds to me like if the mechanical axis is pointing to the left of the left-side solar panel, then it will naturally find a neutral point that is completely opposite to the correct one (facing the sun).

Comment: A negative signal voltage, indicating sun is on the left side, would rotate the array left until the left and right voltage balances to zero

Comment: Can you post a schematic of one of your bridge circuits showing the inputs in particular?

Comment: Added proposed schematic

Answer (score 0):

If the voltage of sensor is above +0.6V the T1 and T3 conduct. Is lower than -0.6V the T2 and T4 conduct. You can remove these offsets placing a diode into T1 and T2 bases but the motor will run all the time. Also you can avoid dual supply by mirroring this circuit for right side of motor also (full bridge).

[image]